# What kind of adder does the default Verilog addition operator implement?

Tags: verilog

If I want to add two 16-bit inputs, for example, using the default + operator, what kind of adder will this implement in hardware?

Answer (score 6):

This is implementation-dependent. The synthesizer will choose the best hardware solution available, depending on the options that were built into its software and the constraints that you specify for the design.

For an FPGA you might get whatever dedicated adder logic is built in to the FPGA fabric. For a standard-cell ASIC the adder will be constructed from more primitive logic elements, such as NAND and NOR gates. In this case a good synthesizer might consider carry-lookahead or carry-skip architectures instead of a simple ripple-carry adder but this depends entirely on the synthesis tool.

Comment: ... depends on the synth tool and what you ask it for. Set different timing constraints and watch it choose the smallest architecture that meets those constraints.

Comment: Even 20 years ago, a really good synthesis tool would -- if you gave it tight timing constraints and some delay -- automatically synthesize a pipelined adder, to boot.

Comment: @TimWescott How do you define the pipeline delay for an addition operator in Verilog?

Comment: @jpa extra register delays before or after the addition? The synthesizer can move combinational logic across a register, if it's smart enough.

Comment: In addition to the nearby registers, you may also need to ask the synthesiser via some "register retiming" option. (Can't say I've had any luck with it on my bigger pipelines, but they were pre Vivado)

Comment: What @user253751 said.  I haven't _done_ this, but my understanding is that you just describe the operation you want done, then you put a stack of delays at the end.  At least 20 years ago this was something that you only got with top-end synthesizers like the Mentor Graphics one -- not what came for free from the FPGA companies.

Answer (score 3):

If it's working right, it will synthesize an adder that meets timing and bit-for-bit implements a 16x16 add.  Beyond that, all bets are off.

If it's better than just "working right", it will synthesize an adder that uses the least resources, or is otherwise somehow "optimal" (possibly with rules that let you change what "optimal" means).  Beyond that, all bets are off.

The critical part of this is that to the first order approximation, *you should not have to care* what type of adder it synthesizes under the hood. You only care that it meets timing, and that you don't run out of floor space.  You should only start caring about what it's doing under the hood if the resulting adder isn't working right, is too big, or is otherwise not suitable for your intended purpose.